# Very scrolls on firefox how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.event-in > a').click(function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ){
        return;
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this).offset().top + $(this).height()+ 200// + 591
    }, 500);

});
```

On chrome it works fine. scrolls as it should to the specified position (200) but here firefox it really goes up very much somewhere at pixels 200 for sure, why is this happening?

Comment: I don't understand the question sorry. Do you mean it scrolls too far? Too fast? To the wrong place? Does it compute the scrollTop correctly or incorrectly in Firefox?

Comment: Because you didn't provide an minimal, reproducible example I guess the results of commands `$(this).offset().top` and `$(this).height()` contains the string 'px', so the browser is unable to made a calculation with strings and numbers.

Comment: @Rup on Firefox, it scrolls too far unlike Chrome

Comment: I'd try not to scroll both `html` and `body` at the same time